# SQL Query to Access Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, acc

The following query keeps giving me errors:

```
INSERT INTO [tableFinalData] (ClientGroupCode, WorkActivity, SubProj, ClientCode, Client
                           , ProjectYear, StaffCode, ProjectCode, Hours, Rate, Amount, BillingStatus) 
SELECT g.EntityNo AS [GroupName]
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.WorkCodeNo
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.WorkCodeName
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EntityNo
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EntityName
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.ProjectTypeYearNo
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EmployeeNo
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.SubprojectTypeNo
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.Quantity
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.Rate
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.Amount
     , dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.BillingStatus 
FROM ((dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric 
INNER JOIN dbo.EntityConnections AS [c] ON c.EntityId = dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EntityId)
INNER JOIN dbo.Entities AS [g] ON c.GroupId = dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EntityId)
''IN [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=FRANSWINDOWS10\SQLEXPRESS;Database=D:\USERS\FRANS\DOCUMENTS\WORK\SQL DATABASE\CATC14.MDF;Trusted_Connection=yes];
```

This runs just fine when I run it in SQL server.

> ERROR: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in  JOIN
>   operation. Error Code: -3510

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to many parentheses. Either add alias:

```
FROM ((dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric 
INNER JOIN dbo.EntityConnections AS [c] ON c.EntityId = dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EntityId)
INNER JOIN dbo.Entities AS [g] ON c.GroupId = dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EntityId) t
```

or get rid of all of them:

```
FROM dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric 
INNER JOIN dbo.EntityConnections AS [c] ON c.EntityId = dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EntityId
INNER JOIN dbo.Entities AS [g] ON c.GroupId = dbo.vw_TransWIPGeneric.EntityId
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I have to add parentheses since this is MS Access.